# VisualHg Crashing VS2010 mercurial plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, visualhg

Whenever i try VisualHG commits visual studio is crashing? any idea why this is happening?

or is there any better plugin than this for vs2010 and mercurial

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of VisualHG do you have, and which version of TortoiseHg do you have?

Comment: I don't have this issue. I'm using VisualHG 1.1.4, TortoiseHg 2.0.4 64bit on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: I'm using TortoiseHg 2.0.3 and VisualHG 1.1.4

Comment: Worked fine after i upgraded to 2.0.4 :)  thanks cavemen  :) n thanks guys

Comment: Aneef, you can answer your own question and accept it. That way everybody knows your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another mercurial plugin for MS Visual Studio 2008/2010.

http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html

Comment: +1 for hgscc but i still prefer visualhg :). got it working after installing the latest :)